# Redux & Immutable.js - set state from json

Tags: json, node.js, redux, immutable.js

my reducer

```
var initialState = Map({
 status: true 
 });
function user(state = initialState, action) { 
 switch (action.type) {
   case GET_PROFILE: 
   return state.set(fromJS(action.response))
  }
  })
```

api which returns json -> `action.response`

```
{

   "id": 11,
   "profileImage": "http://www.surfertoday.com/images/stories/addictivesurfing.jpg"  

}
```

**The problem:** `fromJS` sets a new `Map` object, instead of adding data to existing `Map`. I tried to do something like 
`return state.set(Array(fromJS(action.response)))` which doesn't work.

---

How can I fix this? Or should I not use Immutable.js for this?

Comment: Use `merge` instead of `set`

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you do want it to return a new map, as the point of redux/immutable is you're returning a new state object with your changes, rather than mutating an existing object.

It's tough to say why this isn't working for you because I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. I think the case "GET_PROFILE" could probably be renamed to something more specific?

This example isn't perfect but may give you some insight: https://github.com/rogic89/ToDo-react-redux-immutable/blob/master/src/reducers/todos.js

If you post more info or add more code I may be able to offer more insight.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to do is update the state with new values retrieved from some kind of request.

You have written action in reducer which is not updating store with new values.

[Immutable.js Map/set](https://web.archive.org/web/20190121010733/http://facebook.github.io:80/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set) function expects two parameters key and a value you are providing only key.

[Immutable.js Map/merge](https://web.archive.org/web/20190121010733/http://facebook.github.io:80/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/merge) use merge instead and combine state of the store with data from response.

```
var initialState = Map({
  status: true 
});

function user(state = initialState, action) { 
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PROFILE: 
    return state.merge(fromJS(action.response))
  }
})
```

You will get

```
{
   status: true, 
   id: 11,
   profileImage: "http://www.surfertoday.com/images/stories/addictivesurfing.jpg" 
}
```